Quais os requisitos mínimos para implementar EF Core?
Estou com dificuldade em encontrar os requisitos mínimos para incluir suporte EF Core em um projeto web.
Entendendo o cenário:
Estou criando um projeto novo, com template "web", ou seja vazio.

dotnet new web -n Project1

Gostaria de saber quais os pacotes básicos para implementar o suporte EF Core?
utilizo banco de dados Firebird 2.5
Obrigado.

olá, já leu a documentação? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/install

Os pacotes são esses:
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Além disso, configure o DbContext e adicione a chamada dele no program/startup do seu projeto
